# rc.local on ubuntu on ec2 will not work

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, startup

Below are the contents of my rc.local file.  When I run sudo /etc/rc.local it works fine.  When I boot up and instance.  I expect monit to be installed but it is not.  I am at a total loss.  I usually use rc.local but this is rather confunsing.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

apt-get -y install monit
/etc/init.d/monit stop
cd /home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/
git fetch
git checkout origin/master rtb_ec2_boot/ec2_boot.py
git checkout origin/master config/
cp /home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/config/monit/redis/monitrc /etc/monit/
/usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtb_ec2_boot/ec2_boot.py >>  /home/ubuntu/workspace/ec2_boot.txt 2>&1

/etc/init.d/monit start
chkconfig monit on

exit 0
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to start the script with:

```
apt-get update
```

as your apt cache might be out of date for the "apt-get install".

You can also debug the script by starting it with these two lines:

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
exec > >(tee /var/log/rc.local.log|logger -t rc.local -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1
```

This will echo each command and its output to /var/log/rc.local.log so you can find out what is failing and with what error.

Make sure the file is executable:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/rc.local
```

Note that rc.local is run on *every* boot, not just the first boot.  Make sure that you are ok with it being run again after the system has been up for a while.

Here's an article I wrote with more details about the "exec" command above: http://alestic.com/2010/12/ec2-user-data-output

Comment: thanks.  I tried but still to no avail.    This is rather odd.

Comment: Please provide more details on what happens when you start rc.local with those two lines and reboot.  Is the file /var/log/rc.local.log created?  What does it contain?

Comment: I have noticed the same behavior. /etc/rc.local is not called after reboot

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used CRLF [line endings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) within rc.local accidentally. After converting them to LF endings, my rc.local was finally executed.

*Wrong*

```
#!/bin/sh\r\n
#\r\n
# This script will be executed *after* all the other init scripts.\r\n
# You can put your own initialization stuff in here if you don't
# want to do the full Sys V style init stuff.\r\n
\r\n
touch /var/lock/subsys/local\r\n
```

*Correct*

```
#!/bin/sh\n
...
```